# How would I go about creating an .env file for my discord bot token?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So, I was recently told that just storing the Discord Bot token in a variable at the top is bad practice and a .env file would be better. Can someone explain to me how I would create the .env file with the token in it and import it into my bot.py file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a libary/module called `python-dotenv`, install the library with

```
pip install python-dotenv
```

To use it in your code, you have to import the `os` module as well as the freshly installed `dotenv` package

```py
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
```

At the beginning of your code after the imports you should have `load_dotenv()` to load the `.env` file.
Then you can use `os.getenv("DOTENV variablename here")` to get the content of the file.

Instruction List:

1. `pip install python-dotenv`.
2. Create a file named `.env` in the root of your project.
3. Write one line: DISCORD_TOKEN = your token (no quotes needed)
4. you should have `import os` and `from dotenv import load_dotenv` in your code.
5. Call `load_dotenv()` at the beginning of your program to load the file.
6. To get your token, you just have to do `os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN")`.

Example code:

```py
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

TOKEN = os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN")
```

Example dotenv file:

```
DISCORD_TOKEN=this.is.my.token.blah.blah.blah
```

Comment: When I do os.getenv, it returns as None, how can I fix this?

Comment: I actually missed a step so I just fixed it. (Look at steps 4 and 5)

Comment: When i run this it returns error basically saying that there is no strip function