# How to get token from token.env with Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, environment-variables, discord.py

So I am trying to get my bot token from token.env but I get a compiler error.
`client.run(os.getenv("TOKEN"))`
and then my token.env is this
`TOKEN["insert token here"]`
I'm not 100% sure how to format that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this question helping you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63530888/how-would-i-go-about-creating-an-env-file-for-my-discord-bot-token

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How would I go about creating an .env file for my discord bot token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63530888/how-would-i-go-about-creating-an-env-file-for-my-discord-bot-token)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.env files are a deprecated method from replit! If you go to your sidebar and click on the lock icon (middle of the list), you'll see a tab called secrets, then all you need to do is make the key whatever, and put your token as the value, click "add new secret", then use

```py
import os
token = os.environ['DISCORD_TOKEN']
```

Replace DISCORD_TOKEN with whatever you decide to name it, then to run it's just

```py
client.run(token)
```

which is much more readable

Answer (score 1):

Make a .env file in the current directory, your file content should look like this

```sh
TOKEN_KEY=TOKEN_VALUE
```

Install `python-dotenv` module

```sh
pip install python-dotenv
```

Add these two line in you Discord.py file

```py
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
```

This is work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try making the file name `.env` instead of `token.env`

Edit: If that doesn't work, you could try this to make a new .env;
[How would I go about creating an .env file for my discord bot token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63530888/how-would-i-go-about-creating-an-env-file-for-my-discord-bot-token)

Comment: repl.it doesn't seem to allow me to make just .env, I need something before it.

Comment: In repl.it, there is a lock symbol to the left called `Secrets`. In "Secrets", to the `key` section, write TOKEN, and to the `value` section, write your token. Then presss `Add new secret`.    
  
Then `client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))` will work.  (Replit recently removed .env files and replaced them with the Secrets section)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a libary/module called `python-dotenv`, install the library with

```
pip install python-dotenv
```

To use it in your code, you have to import the os module as well as the freshly installed dotenv package

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
```

At the beginning of your code after the imports you should have `load_dotenv()` to load the .env file. Then you can use `os.getenv("DOTENV variablename here")` to get the content of the file.

Instruction List:

```
pip install python-dotenv.
```

Create a file named .env in the root of your project.
Write one line: `DISCORD_TOKEN = your token` (no quotes needed)
you should have import os and from dotenv import `load_dotenv` in your code.
Call `load_dotenv()` at the beginning of your program to load the file.
To get your token, you just have to do

```
os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN").
```

**Example code:**

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

TOKEN = os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN")
Example dotenv file:

DISCORD_TOKEN=this.is.my.token.blah.blah.blah
```

Answer taken from here: [How would I go about creating an .env file for my discord bot token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63530888/how-would-i-go-about-creating-an-env-file-for-my-discord-bot-token)