# Discord bot "RuntimeError: Cannot close a running event loop" error

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I keep getting this error "RuntimeError: Cannot close a running event loop" whenever I run the code below, tried many solutions but none of them worked.

I am using jupyter notebook,
`print(discord.__version__)` --> 1.7.3

Thanks in advance.

```
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()

import discord
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63530888/how-would-i-go-about-creating-an-env-file-for-my-discord-bot-token


client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
    
    
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == message.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')
        
        
TOKEN = os.getenv("token")

client.run('TOKEN')
```

code output:

> Task exception was never retrieved future: <Task finished
> name='Task-21' coro=<Client.run..runner() done, defined at
> C:\Users\username\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py:700>
> exception=LoginFailure('Improper token has been passed.')> Traceback
> (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\username\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line
> 300, in static_login
> data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))   File "C:\Users\username\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line
> 254, in request
> raise HTTPException(r, data) discord.errors.HTTPException: 401 Unauthorized (error code: 0): 401: Unauthorized
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> ### Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\username\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 280, in __step
> result = coro.send(None)   File "C:\Users\username\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line
> 702, in runner
> await self.start(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\username\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line
> 665, in start
> await self.login(*args, bot=bot)   File "C:\Users\username\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line
> 511, in login
> await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)   File "C:\Users\username\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line
> 304, in static_login
> raise LoginFailure('Improper token has been passed.') from exc discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-ccfa19a2810e> in <module>
     26 TOKEN = os.getenv("token")
     27 
---> 28 client.run('TOKEN')
     29 
     30 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py in run(self, *args, **kwargs)
    717             future.remove_done_callback(stop_loop_on_completion)
    718             log.info('Cleaning up tasks.')
--> 719             _cleanup_loop(loop)
    720 
    721         if not future.cancelled():

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py in _cleanup_loop(loop)
     93     finally:
     94         log.info('Closing the event loop.')
---> 95         loop.close()
     96 
     97 class _ClientEventTask(asyncio.Task):

~\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\selector_events.py in close(self)
     87     def close(self):
     88         if self.is_running():
---> 89             raise RuntimeError("Cannot close a running event loop")
     90         if self.is_closed():
     91             return

RuntimeError: Cannot close a running event loop
```

Comment: Please post the ***whole*** traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Change the last line from `client.run('TOKEN')` to `client.run(TOKEN)`. You are using the string `"TOKEN"` not the variable `TOKEN`.

Comment: Changed it and still getting the error.

Comment: I tried running your code and got a different error - "NoneType object can't be stripped", but it was caused by the fact you never run load_dotenv() which should be run before trying to access values in the .env file. If you run this at the start of the file it might work.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work, and I still get the same error.

Comment: That's odd - it runs fine for me. The only other thing I can suggest is to make sure the token in the .env file is correct.

Comment: The code works fine on an online ide, on jupyter notebook I get the "RunTimeError". I am missing something and I can't figure what is it.

Comment: The token is correct just checked it.